# C++ __COUNTER__ definition

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I have two versions of a C++ compiler installed on my computer. One of them recognizes the `__COUNTER__` macro and the other does not.

After doing some research to make the program compile in both, I have yet to come across the macro definition for `__COUNTER__`. Is this some special macro done by the compiler or can I copy the definition for `__COUNTER__` into my source code? If I can copy it, what is the code I need?

Comment: Are you using to create unique identifiers?  Example: `#define GLUE(var) (var ## __COUNTER__)`.

Comment: I am using it in an obfuscation challenge to do preprocessor loops. @FiddlingBits

Comment: Boost.PP has one of these.

Comment: What compiler was it, by the way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`__COUNTER__` is a built-in in several common compilers. It is not possible to define manually. If you're stuck with a compiler that doesn't support it, your best option might be to run your code through a preprocessor that does support it before feeding it into the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

It's a special macro which has been introduced by Visual Studio and I think is now supported by GCC too.

It basically provides a unique counter over integral numbers which can be used to generate unique identifiers.

From [GCC release notes](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/changes.html):

> A new predefined macro `__COUNTER__` has been added. It expands to sequential integral values starting from 0. In conjunction with the `##` operator, this provides a convenient means to generate unique identifiers.

If you don't have it available to a compiler you can easily mimic the behavior with a static variable. But I'm not sure what you are compiling so I'm not sure how this counter is used in the code you have available.

Comment: You can't increment a variable with the preprocessor... how would using a variable work?

Comment: @FiddlingBits I wrote a little hack once that has a `INIT` macro that set `COUNTER=0;`, and another macro which included `COUNTER++;`. It is not fully functional, but it can server pretty well, despite requiring a global variable.

Comment: @FiddlingBits: it depends how the actual `__COUNTER__` macro is used inside the code. You could be able to mimic the behavior or not according to how the generated number is used.

Comment: Do you use `#define` and `#undef` repeatedly?

Comment: @FiddlingBits, Take a look at [Boost's](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/counter.html).

Comment: @chris Looks interesting, but it doesn't expose the guts, huh?

Comment: @FiddlingBits, Check your installation. It's definitely open source and it's actually interesting how high it can go.