# C: Concatenating __COUNTER__ with a string

Tags: c

I want to stringify the `__COUNTER__` and print it as a string not an integer. Is that possible?

```
printf("%s\n", #__COUNTER__);
```

I have tried the following, but it does not work.

```
hello.c:6:19: error: stray ‘#’ in program
printf("%s\n",#__COUNTER__);
```

Comment: What is the definition of counter?  Also, you should not be using `#` to use a macro, only to define it.

Comment: Counter is a monotonically incrementing integer, which is available in the gcc version which I am using

Comment: `printf("%d", __COUNTER__);` I have no idea what it means to "print as a string".

Comment: I want a string not an integer

Comment: Oh, I see, it is predefined.  You will need a stringify macro

Comment: And how integer is different from string when printed?

Comment: :) when printed it isn't but prior to printing it is. It is a small example used to demonstrate that I want a string not an integer.

Comment: then just use `snprintf` with `%d`. I have a feeling that the macro proposed in the answer is not really what you need. Better describe the real problem.

Comment: I do need a compile time constant, snprintf wouldn't solve my problem. I wish it was that simple :)

Comment: Ok, then the answers are what you need. Apparently to concatenate it with something else you will need to add another level of indirection. Always think in terms of preprocessor passes. Think like preprocessor :)

Comment: [`__COUNTER__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20768379/c-counter-definition/20768388#20768388): *"...a special macro which has been introduced by [Visual&nbsp;Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio) and I think is now supported by [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) too"*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but it takes an indirection because you can't use the `#` operator outside of a macro.

```
#define STRINGIFY_2(a) #a
#define STRINGIFY(a) STRINGIFY_2(a)

printf("%s\n", STRINGIFY(__COUNTER__));
```

The double macro is required to expand `__COUNTER__`, otherwise the result would be `"__COUNTER__"`.

If you don't want to reinvent that wheel, that's exactly what [`BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/stringize.html) does.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the first STRINGIFY(__ COUNTER __) would result in STRINGIFY_2(0) which would then result in "0"? (didn't know that # is only valid in a macro definition)

Comment: @Har exactly! -

Comment: Is the double-macro dance really needed for this use case?  I thought that was only needed when pasting things together.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons [yes](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.stringize#2), for the same reason, that is neither `##` nor `#` expand their argument(s) before pasting or stringizing them.

Comment: Oh, right.  I knew there was something I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to stringify it with a preprocessor macro.

```
#define XSTR(s) STR(s)
#define STR(s) #s
printf("%s", XSTR(counter));
```